# Импорт базы данных в sugar orm

Tags: android, база-данных, sugarorm

Мне нужно, чтобы можно было из файла загрузить базу данных в приложение, использую *sugar orm*. Что нужно использовать, чтобы это можно было сделать?

UPD:  Импорт из файла sql , текстового файла, не суть важно. Я хочу заполнить на компьютере базу данных и поместить ее в приложение.
UPD: Почитал, разобрался с программами для заполнения базы данных. Ну вот создам я ее и как ее потом в само приложение загрузить?

Comment: Про какой именно файл идет речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SugarORM - это по факту обертка под Android для баз формата SQLite.

Т.е. по сути задача сводится к тому чтобы на компьютере каким-то образом создать/заполнить/отредактировать базу данных.

Сделать это можно многими способами.

Самый простой - это с помощью утилиты коммандной строки sqlite3

Можно найти приложение с графическим интерфейсом для работы с базой. Но это для тех кто любит "работать руками".

Так же sqlite поддерживается в большинстве языков программирования. Тут тоже богатый выбор на чем написать скрипт или программу, которые бы читали исходный файл и заполняли базу. Все завист только от ваших знаний.

Сайт проекта SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/